# Ionic Cloud authentication with Lumen server

Tags: laravel, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2, lumen

I am currently using Ionic Cloud to handle authentication and Facebook login for my app. What I am now doing is building a backend API with Lumen to do a few simple things that Ionic Cloud can't do. Is there a way to use the authentication I already have with Ionic Cloud to also authenticate my back end server? Or will I need to scrap Cloud and only implement authentication in Lumen. Ionic Cloud makes authentication very neat and easy, so it would be a shame to stop using it.